# PowerShell script too slow

Tags: windows, powershell, optimization, scripting

Need help with speeding up the script as it is going to be run against 10-20K servers. Currently tested on 4K servers and took almost 6 hours. Tried running it asjob (One parent job and 4000 childjobs, it runs fine and a lot faster but the parent job gets stuck in "running" state forever. It is because one of the childjobs stays in "Notstarted" state. Not sure how to fix that.

######################################################################################

```
$today = Get-Date
$path = (Get-Location).Path
$path += "\"
$date = Get-Date -uformat "%Y%m%d%H%M"
$Inputfile = $path + "Computers.txt"
$outfile = $path + "Report\" + "Certificate_Report_$date.csv"
$transcript = $path + "Logs\" + "Transcript_$date.log"

Start-Transcript $transcript

$computers = gc $Inputfile

Foreach ($c in $computers){

$cert = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $c -ScriptBlock{Get-ChildItem Cert:\localmachine -Recurse} -ErrorVariable issue -ErrorAction Continue

If ($issue){
$Connection = $Error[0].FullyQualifiedErrorId
$obj1 = New-Object Psobject
$Obj1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Server -Value $c
$Obj1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Serverconnection -Value $Connection
#$report += $obj1
$obj1 | Export-Csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation -Append -force
}
Else{$Connection = "Success"}


Foreach ($cer in $cert){

if($cer.Thumbprint -ne $null){

$obj = New-Object Psobject
$Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Server -Value $c
$Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Serverconnection -Value $Connection
$Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PsParentpath -Value $Cer.PsParentpath
$Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Subject -Value $Cer.Subject
$Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Thumbprint -Value $Cer.Thumbprint
$Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DnsNamelist -Value $Cer.DNSNamelist
$Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FriendlyName -Value $Cer.FriendlyName
$Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Issuer -Value $Cer.Issuer
$Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Valid_From -Value $Cer.NotBefore
$Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Expiration_Date -Value $Cer.NotAfter

if ($cer.NotAfter -lt $today){
$status = "Expired"
}
Else{$status = "Valid"}

$Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Cert_Status -Value $status
$obj | Export-Csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation -Append

}
}
}


Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: [1] take a look at `Invoke-Command`. that accepts a list of systems, a scriptblock, and any other items needed ... and runs the code on the target systems in parallel. [2] this seems likely to be a better fit for the `Code Review` site, but i aint gonna mote to close it since it am unsure of that.

Comment: Thanks Lee. I tried running something like this. Which is quick but one childjob was stuck at "notsstarted" and that causes the parent job to be stuck.Not sure how to handle the childjob state.  $job = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock{Get-ChildItem Cert:\localmachine -Recurse} -AsJob -ThrottleLimit 15
While ((Get-Job).State -eq "Running"){
If ((((Get-Job).ChildJobs).Hasmoredata -eq "True").count -gt "200"){
$data = $job.ChildJobs | where{$_.state -eq "Completed"} | Receive-Job}

Comment: don't start a job INSIDE the `Invoke-Command`. [*grin*] don't use jobs AT ALL. read the docs on the `I-C` cmdlet and use that. for a small example, look at this ... >>> basic remote parallel SystemInfo demo script - Pastebin.com — https://pastebin.com/cGL5biWH <<<

Comment: Thanks a ton Lee. Referred the link and made changes to the script and its a lot faster. Spent too much time trying to make it work as a Job :p

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only obvious optimization that comes to mind (without parallelizing the remote queries) is to avoid `| Add-Member` and use `[pscustomobject]` syntax for the result objects:

```
$today = Get-Date
$date = Get-Date -uformat "%Y%m%d%H%M"
$Inputfile = (Resolve-Path "Computers.txt").Path
$outfile = (Resolve-Path "Report\Certificate_Report_$date.csv").Path
$transcript = (Resolve-Path "Logs\Transcript_$date.log").Path

Start-Transcript $transcript

$computers = gc $Inputfile

Foreach ($c in $computers) {

    $cert = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $c -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem Cert:\localmachine -Recurse } -ErrorVariable issue -ErrorAction Continue

    If ($issue) {
        $Connection = $Error[0].FullyQualifiedErrorId
        $obj1 = [pscustomobject]@{
            Server = $c
            Serverconnection = $Connection
        } | Export-Csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation -Append -force
    }
    Else {
        $Connection = "Success"
    }

    Foreach ($cer in $cert) {
        if ($null -ne $cer.Thumbprint) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Server = $c
                Serverconnection = $Connection
                PsParentpath = $Cer.PsParentpath
                Subject = $Cer.Subject
                Thumbprint = $Cer.Thumbprint
                DnsNamelist = $Cer.DNSNamelist
                FriendlyName = $Cer.FriendlyName
                Issuer = $Cer.Issuer
                Valid_From = $Cer.NotBefore
                Expiration_Date = $Cer.NotAfter
                Cert_Status = if ($cer.NotAfter -lt $today) { "Expired" } else { "Valid" }
            } | Export-Csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation -Append
        }
    }
}

Stop-Transcript
```

As [Lee_Dailey mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63546638/powershell-script-too-slow#comment112370511_63546638), you might also want to try offloading parallel execution of the remoting commands to `Invoke-Command` completely, by passing it all the computer names up front:

```bsh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem Cert:\localmachine -Recurse} -ErrorAction Continue |For-EachObject {
  # Process the results here
}
```

If you want help troubleshooting using background jobs, please post the code with which you have problems :)

Comment: Thanks Mathias for the detailed instructions. With the information you shared and the help from Lee, modified the script. 20 mins to process 4K servers!!

Comment: @PoojaHegde that's great! If you feel like my response doesn't _comprehensively_ answer your question, I strongly suggest you [post an answer yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and document/explain the changes that allowed for this significant improvement! :-)

Comment: actually it kinda does. But yes it would be better to post the final script here. Will do So. :)

Answer (score 0):

Script posted in my question took almost 6 hours to do the same thing this modified version does in under 30 mins. Grateful for the help on this post. Final script below:

```
$today = Get-Date
$date = Get-Date -uformat "%Y%m%d%H%M"
$Inputfile = gc (Resolve-Path "Computers.txt").Path
$outfile = (Resolve-Path "Report\").Path + "Certificate_Report_$date.csv"
$transcript = (Resolve-Path "Logs\").Path + "Transcript_$date.log"
$failed = "Couldn't retrieve Data"

$IC_ScriptBlock = {Get-ChildItem Cert:\localmachine -Recurse}
$IC_Params = @{
    ComputerName = $Inputfile
    ScriptBlock = $IC_ScriptBlock
    ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
        }
$responding = Invoke-Command @IC_Params|ForEach-Object {
if ($null -ne $_.Thumbprint) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Server = $_.pscomputername
                PsParentpath = $_.PsParentpath
                Subject = $_.Subject
                Thumbprint = $_.Thumbprint
                DnsNamelist = $_.DNSNamelist
                FriendlyName = $_.FriendlyName
                Issuer = $_.Issuer
                Valid_From = $_.NotBefore
                Expiration_Date = $_.NotAfter
                Cert_Status = if ($_.NotAfter -lt $today) { "Expired" } else { "Valid" }
            } | Export-Csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation -Append
        }
        }

$not_responding = $Inputfile.Where({
$_ -notin $responding.Pscomputername -and "[$_]" -notin $responding.pscomputername
}).

foreach({
[pscustomobject]@{
                Server = $_
                PsParentpath = $failed
                Subject = $failed
                Thumbprint = $failed
                DnsNamelist = $failed
                FriendlyName = $failed
                Issuer = $failed
                Valid_From = $failed
                Expiration_Date = $failed
                Cert_Status = "NA"
                } | Export-Csv $outfile -Append -NoTypeInformation
                
                })
```

Comment: Just a side note: I have little experience with PS so I would have done this using a `Class` instead of `[pscustomobject]`, just because it is more like C# (that I do know better than PS), not because it would be better or anything. It would be interesting to see if there is a performance gain (or loss) when using classes.

Comment: PowerShell 5x and beyond has support for classes.  Not need to an external language to do that. [about_Classes - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7), and there are use cases for them of course.  [A practical case for using a PowerShell Class
](http://powershelldistrict.com/powershell-class/). See also. [the Add-Type cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-7) when needing other language resources.

Comment: @postanote not sure if you are alluding to my comment but I did mean classes in PS.

Comment: @Arno van Boven, yeppers, but the way it read it was like you were saying you wanted to create a class in C#, or the like and use that in PS. But, I'm old, and well, you know, OPP (old people problems) kicks in whenever it chooses.